# How to keep music playing when calling videoView.start()?

Tags: android, video

I'm using a VideoView in my Android app to display a video.

If other app is playing music in the background, calling videoview.start() stops music playing by other apps  in the background.

Is there a way to make sure any music in the background will keep playing at the same time with calling video view.start()? (it has no audio)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was also in the same scenario: My requirement is, I need to play a splash video without affecting the background music. My Splash video don't have any audio. So create a custom video view and commented below lines of code under openVideo():

```
//  AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//  am.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Now My video view XML is:

```
<com.videosample.CustomVideoView
     android:id="@+id/vv_splash_video"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_common_five_dp_padding"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:visibility="visible" />
```

Inside the activity I added like this:

```
mVvSplashVideo = (CustomVideoView) findViewById(R.id.vv_splash_video);
mVvSplashVideo.setZOrderOnTop(true);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
    getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample_splash_v4_1);
mVvSplashVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
isVideoPlayCompleted=false;
mVvSplashVideo.start();
mVvSplashVideo.setOnCompletionListener(this);
```

Hope this will help for you.

Comment: **I have same Issue**
I want to keep playing music of other music player app.but when My app video play start then music stop.so please share your" CustomVideoView " class